# Spark Streaming states to be persisted to disk in addition to in memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have written a program using spark streaming by using map with state function which detect repetitive records and avoid such records..the function is similar as bellow:

```
val trackStateFunc1 = (batchTime: Time, 
                       key: String,  
                       value: Option[(String,String)],
                       state: State[Long]) => {
  if (state.isTimingOut()) {
    None
  }
  else if (state.exists()) None
  else {
    state.update(1L)
    Some(value.get)
  }
}

val stateSpec1 = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc1)
//.initialState(initialRDD)
.numPartitions(100)
.timeout(Minutes(30*24*60))
```

My numbers of records could be high and I kept the time-out for about one month. Therefore, number of records and keys could be high..I wanted to know if I can save these states on Disk in addition to the Memory..something like 
"RDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)"

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I can save these states on Disk in addition to the
>   Memory

Stateful streaming in Spark automatically get serialized to persistent storage, this is called [*checkpointing*](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing). When you run your stateful DStream, you must provide a checkpoint directory otherwise the graph won't be able to execute at runtime.

You can set the checkpointing interval via `DStream.checkpoint`. For example, if you want to set it to every 30 seconds:

```
inputDStream
 .mapWithState(trackStateFunc)
 .checkpoint(Seconds(30))
```

Comment: I think your answer is inaccurate..I meant the internal state DStream (InternalMapWithStateDStream) which kept by spark for each batch (see this link:https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-streaming/spark-streaming-mapwithstatedstreams.html)..That by default is only presisted in memory..my question is that if states are so large which can not be cached just in Memory..if it raise exception or being recomputed?

Answer (score 0):

Accourding to "MapWithState" sources you can try:

```scala
mapWithStateDS.dependencies.head.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

actual for spark 3.0.1